# n_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class error

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas, decisiontreeclassifier

I'm trying to build validation curve that relying on max_depth but keep getting an error:

```
n_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.
```

I tried to put n_splits with different values, error doesnt change. I got data from .cvs file with numeric data

Here is code fragment that gets error:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=123)
    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=132)
    train_scores, valid_scores = validation_curve(model, X, y, param_name="max_depth", n_jobs=-1,
       param_range=np.arange(1, 20), cv=10, scoring="accuracy")
```

Im working in Jupiter Lite.

Comment: Per the error, how many samples do you have to for each class label?

Comment: not sure that i understand what you are asking, im working with table with 18 colums and 442 row for each

Comment: The error is telling you that at least one of your targets, the classes you're trying to predict, has less than 10 samples/rows. Out of your 442 rows, check to see how many represent each target class